# Android Room use Type Converter insert success but can't query

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

`Room 2.4.2`

I need store the `List<Int>` data to database , so I  convert the numbers to a `String`,this is convert code , I add it to my database and i insert data success :

```
class Converter {

    /** list<Int> -> [1][2] */
    @TypeConverter
    fun numberToStr(numbers: List<Int>): String {
        val sb = StringBuffer()
        numbers.forEach {
            sb.append("[$it]")
        }
        return sb.toString()
    }

    /** [1][2] -> list<Int> */
    @TypeConverter
    fun strToNumber(str: String): List<Int> {
        val numbers = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val regex = Regex("""\d+""")
        val numMatchResult = regex.findAll(str).toList()
        numMatchResult.forEach {
            numbers.add(it.value.toInt())
        }
        return numbers
    }
}
```

The data in database like this: `[15145][15145][15145][15145]...` as a `TEXT` type, and this `Entity`

```
@Entity(tableName = "detectAd")
data class DetectAd(
    val sampleNo: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val adNo: Int,
    var Ad1: List<Int>,
    var Ad2: List<Int>,
    var Ad3: List<Int>,
    var Ad4: List<Int>,
    var Ad5: List<Int>,
    var Ad6: List<Int>,
    var Ad7: List<Int>,
    var Ad8: List<Int>
)
```

Then this is `Dao` and `Query` function , `getAd3Numbers` tip error!

```
// could work
    @Query("SELECT Ad3 FROM detectAd WHERE sampleNo = :sampleNo")
    fun getAd3Str(sampleNo: String): String
// error ,and can't encoding!
    @Query("SELECT Ad3 FROM detectAd WHERE sampleNo = :sampleNo")
    fun getAd3Numbers(sampleNo: String): List<Int>
```

error message:

```
The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [value] in java.lang.Integer even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [Ad3]
    public abstract java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> getAd3Numbers(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

So, it's my code wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What room is saying is that there is no column in the output (result of the query) called **value**, it has only found a column called **ad3**.

To overcome that you could give the column an alias/different name by using:-

```
@Query("SELECT Ad3 AS value FROM detectAd WHERE sampleNo = :sampleNo")
    fun getAd3Numbers(sampleNo: String): List<Int>
```

**BUT** you will not get the result you expect. As Room will take the List to be that you expect a number of rows each with a single value of Type Int.

You may then expect `List<List<Int>>` to work but then Room isn't aware of the TypeConverter and you get

```
Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>).
public abstract java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>> getAd3NumbersV2(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

What you can do, is have a POJO such as :-

```
data class AdPojo(
    val Ad3: List<Int>
)
```

- note that using the above POJO means Room will expect the column to be named **`Ad3`** and nothing but. However you could use `SELECT Ad4 AS Ad3 FROM detectAd ....`  to get the Ad4 column (or likewise for Ad1-Ad8)

and then use

```
@Query("SELECT Ad3 FROM detectAd WHERE sampleNo=:sampleNo")
fun getAd3NumberV3(sampleNo: String): List<AdPojo>
```

As an example. Data in the database is:-

[image]

When run with a breakpoint immediately after `val ad3 = adDao.getAd3NumberV3("S001")` then when the breakpoint is reached the following is displayed:-

[image]